# How do I import a Haskell package into the REPL for interactive use?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I'm new to Haskell, and have found the `:type` command in the `ghci` REPL to be really useful for interactively figuring out how things work. So far I've only used things from the base package, but now I'd like to use something from [`distributive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.4.4/docs/Data-Distributive.html#v:collect) with the `:type` command in the REPL.

How in the world do I do this? If it matters, I'm on macOS and have done `brew install ghc cabal-install`. But nothing I've tried will either install or import the `distributive` package, and the error messages are not very good. I've found lots of related questions and documentation, but nothing shows a worked example, and I'm unable to infer what commands to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. The missing pieces were needing to first update `cabal` (even though I had just installed it), and to use `--lib` as an argument when installing:

1. `brew install ghc cabal-install`
2. `cabal update`
3. `cabal install --lib distributive`
4. `ghci`
5. `import Data.Distributive`